# Laravel Validation MessageBag contains errors however not showing up in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am trying to show any validation error in the blade file.

Below I have provided how my controller looks like :

```
$rules =array(
    'mobile' => 'required_without:landline',
    'landline' => 'required_without:mobile'
);
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
//process
if($validator->fails()){
    //$fieldsWithErrorMessagesArray = $validator->messages();
    //dd($fieldsWithErrorMessagesArray);

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
}
```

This is how my blade file looks like :

```
<?php
      echo print_r($errors,true);
?>

@if ($errors->has('mobile'))
     @foreach($errors->get('mobile') as $error)
             <span class="validation_error">{{$error}}</span>
     @endforeach
@endif

@if ($errors->has('landline'))
     @foreach($errors->get('landline') as $error)
             <span class="validation_error">{{$error}}</span>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

When the validation failed in the controlled, I had a 2 lines which I commented out (used for testing to see the error output).

This is what that dd($fieldsWithErrorMessagesArray); generated :

```
MessageBag {#218 ▼
  #messages: array:21 [▼
    "mobile" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The mobile field is required when landline is not present."
    ],
    "landline" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The landline field is required when mobile is not present."
    ]
  ]
}
```

However when I tried echoing out in the blade file, I am getting an empty array

This is how my kernel.php file looks like (located : app/Http/Kernel.php)

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'ajaxOnly' => \App\Http\Middleware\OnlyAjax::class,
];
```

I am using Laravel 5.1. However I have also tried this on 5.8 and still getting the same issue. I am not sure why this is happening any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it is the validation rule. I changed required_without to be just required. This works. However I do want to check if one or the other field is present

Comment: Can you try `Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();`?

Comment: I have tried that, no change the ViewErrorBag object brought back in the blade still seems to be empty. thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: ok, I will let you know once I reach home and reproduce this issue.

Comment: I have just updated my question to show how my kernel.php file looks. I seen a few post talking about moving the StartSession:class line into middleware. However my file structure looks totally different to what I see on the posts..

Comment: Can't say anything now. If file structure is different, it might be because of Laravel version difference.

Comment: Try `return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)`;

Comment: @TheAlpha that worked. Thank you much.

Comment: @TheAlpha do you know how I could get this working with the (->withInput()). As I want to come back to the form with what the user chosen values

Comment: I just installed 5.8 and tried to create the same issue on their as-well. Still no luck of fixing this issue..

Comment: Use/Chain the `->withInput()` method in your controller and in the form fields, use `old('field_name'), ie: old('mobile', 'default_value_goes_here')`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by removing \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\ StartSession::class from 'middleware' in Kernel.php, leaving it in the 'web' group in the same file.

The problem would be that the session only needs to be started only in the 'web' middleware group.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by removing \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\ StartSession::class from 'middleware' in Kernel.php, it must be only in the 'web' group in the same file.